# Downloading additional voices from command-line

Tags: macos, command-line, text-to-speech, speech

I am using a MacOS X server (to which I only have command-line access) to convert text to speech which is saved to sound files (using PyObjC). I would like to install some of the optional OS X voices (for example `com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.tom.premium`) but I need to be able to do this through the command-line rather than via the System Preferences. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you use Sys Prefs?

Comment: I need to do this as part of a Travis (http://travis-ci.org) job, and therefore this ideally all has to be done via the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

You can predownload the voice files to your App/Python package (or however you are distributing your app), and then write a script to move or copy the voice files to this folder:

```
/System/Library/Speech/Voices/
```

So:

> 1. Download the voice files on your development machine
> 2. Wrap them inside an `assets` folder or something like this
> 3. Part of your Travis script can be to move the files first in the Voices folder on the mac
> 4. And after that, you run your tests/other scripts